# Carregar dados da tabela relacionada (Laravel) - Qual a melhor forma?

Tags: laravel, controller, relacionamento

Boa noite.

Na view carregada a partir de: `Route::get('livro/detail/{id}',['uses'=>'LivroController@detail', 'as' => 'livro.detail']);`  eu consigo livremente carregar os dados das colunas da tabela *Livros*, pois no *controller* eu usei o `find` nesse `route`.

Se, por acaso, eu quiser carregar valores da tabela relacionada *Tags*, como eu faço?

Eu fiz de uma forma, mas não fiquei convencido de que é o ideal. A forma é:
`App\Tag::find($livro->tag_id)->nome }}`

Tem alguma forma mais limpa ou desta forma é a forma correta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certo, você não postou código nenhum, não dá para dizer se está certo ou errado, ou o que leva uma rota a ter tantos adereços apenas para recuperar um id, mais você vai precisar fazer uma nova migração ou se quiser, fazer no manual mesmo, via phpmyadmin.

Na migration da tabela livros (**database > migration**), Inclua este código ao final da function UP ( antes de $table->timestamps(); )

```
$table->string('tagcode');    
$table->foreign('tagcode')->references('tagcode')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Na migration da tabela tags (**database > migration**), Inclua este código ao final da function UP ( antes de $table->timestamps(); )

```
$table->string('tagcode')->default(01);
```

Resumidamente você esta dizendo que o livro X usará o tagcode X da tabela 'tags'.
Agora no seu controller:

```
 use App\Models\Livros;
 use App\Models\Tags;

 public function index2($request)
    {
         $livros = Livros::where('tagcode', $request)->first();
         $lid = $livros->id; $taglid = tags::where('id', $lid)->first();  
    
         return view('livros', compact('livros', 'taglid', 'request'));
    }
```

- certifique-se de possuir as models 'livros' e 'tags'.

Em **Routes > web.php** inclua isso ao final:

```
   Route::get('meuslivros/{id}', 'livrosController@index2');
```

- certifique-se de possuir um controller 'livros'.

Em **Resources > Views** crie um arquivo chamado: **livros.blade.php** e adicione o seguinte dentro dele:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <section class="content">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                  <table class="table mb-0">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">codigo da tag</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @forelse($livros as $livros)
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ $livros->id }}</th>
                        <td>{{ $livros->tagcode }}</td>
                      </tr>
                        @empty
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan="6" class="text-danger"><b>sem dados para mostrar.</b></td>
                      </tr>
                       @endforelse
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Pronto, após você criar dados na tabela você pode acessar: seusite.com/meuslivros/(o tagcode do livro na tabela 'livros', sem estas aspas).

- Com `{{ $livros->name }}` você obtém o nome do livro relacionado ao tagcode.
- Com `{{ $tagslid->tagcode }}` você obtém os livros relacionados ao tagcode.

- Você pode usar `{{ $livros }}' e '{{ $taglid }}` com qualquer coisa, desde que a coluna exista na tabela, por exemplo `{{ $livros->id }}` ou `{{ $livros->name }}` e assim por diante, sempre usando `->` para indicar a coluna, lembrando que `{{ $taglid }}` retorna dados relacionados ao tagcode digitado na url e não de toda a tabela 'tags'.

**Paginação**

Se você quiser pode usar paginate para diminuir o estresse do seu BD. No seu controller, inclua o paginate no final da função, dessa forma:

```
$taglid = tags::where('id', $lid)->first()->paginate(10);
```

Depois inclua no final da view ou onde os links deveram aparecer:

`{{ $livros->links() }}` ou `{{ $taglid->links() }}` conforme o seu caso. Você também pode colocar os dois na view, mais tem que ver se não vai estragar o seu design, ele só mostra o botão se você estiver fazendo a busca nessa tabela e houverem dados para mostrar.

- fazendo isso, ele mostrará apenas 10 registro e mostrará também um botão para você ver os demais registros, claro, você pode mudar o 10 que eu coloquei e mudar para 5, dai ele mostrará apenas 5 registros.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Através dessa ajuda, eu consegui achar o que eu queria. O código do controller que você me pediu pra usar, resolveu meu problema, pois ali foi utilizada a variável $taglid pra receber de Tag e passar isso pra minha view. Com isso, eu posso usar livremente a partir da variável $taglid na minha view. Muuuuuuuito obrigado!

Comment: de nada, disponha.